# es6 not working for my custom npm module

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I've just extracted part of my javascript app (written in Vue2 and nuxt.js but that's not important) to an external npm package.

My main app is using babel for es6 code and all the files written in that package are using es6 syntax. The problem is - after extracting es6 code to an external npm module, uglifyjs started to complain about their syntax. Errors suggests that uglify treats them as regular javascript files, not es6.

How can i tell node to treat my package files as es6?

---

#### Edit:

Sorry for not providing a code sample but there is really not much to be shown. I have a regular webpack app generated by nuxt.js/vue-cli generator. It uses babelify and uglify to make it able to use es6 sytnax. All the main app is written using es6.

Let's say i moved two files to external module - `A` and `B` (both in es6). Module `A` requires module `B` and that's when uglify complains - that the `B` file is not written in es5. It seems that module required internally is not getting babelified first for some reason. Is that an expected behaviour?

Comment: what code? all I see are words

Comment: i can't send you the file as it's copyrights-protected but here is the similar fake one: https://gist.github.com/mbajur/bb355a5fd310ab5c59b763c25e744c6c - im trying to require it from another file in that package and that's when things gets messy (uglify complains about unexpected `(` and expecting `:` in line 3)

Comment: How are you using uglify? Ideally, you should be babelifying the code and then uglifying the final result. Naturally, if you feed uglified code into babel, it's probably not going to understand it.

Comment: you want help with code you wont share - looks like it's your problem

Comment: Yeah, that's what i suppose to be happening (i'm at the beginning of my journey with webpack/js/uglify/babel/etc) - it seems that whole application is babelified but when requiring an external file from node_modules - that file is not getting babelified first. I updated my original post to include a bit more details

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry but im not sure what you want me to do. That's my company's application, i can't just send it to you publicly. All i can do is to provide as much details as possible or, eventually, prepare a fake app and share it but that's a lot of work. I was hoping that my issue is a generic one and description will be sufficient to someone. And sure it's my problem, that's why im writing here. If that wasn't my problem, i would post it as a bug report somewhere else.

Comment: nothing, I just stated it's hard to fix code if you can't see the code - I do understand your issue though

Comment: I'm totally aware of that, it's just hard to send the actuall code as there is a lot of it. Please see the edit of my original post. Anyway, maybe i should rewrite my question - if i want to make a npm package using es6 syntax, do i need to specify any special dependencies in that modules package.json or is that a parent-apps responsibility to parse them well on `require` ?

Answer (score 0):

There are few solutions,

one is to mention your extracted module as part of the vendors, so in webpack you will have :

```
entry: {
    ...
    vendor: [
        'jquery', 
        'my-extracted-module'
    ]
},
```

And use the `CommonsChunkPlugin`:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        filename: 'vendor.js'
    })
]
```

And compile `my-extracted-module` as a standalone (you could use es:next feature in it's package.json)

Another solution is just tell webpack to include that package when building, see

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2031